# Login session dosn't work as intended

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have created a login form. When a user is logged in, a session should start, because some pages is only available for users that is logged in. 
All the user data is saved in a mysql database, thats working fine.
When I try to login with a correct email/password thats stored in the mysql database, the page turns back to the file called **hjem.php** thats supposed to be the frontpage for users that's not logged in. I get no error messages.

The php code looks like this in the page where the login form is placed - this file is called **login_user.php**

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 

  $myemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$myemail' and password = '$mypassword'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $active = $row['active'];

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

  if($count == 1) {

     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myemail;

     header("location: login-hjem.php");
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }} ?>
```

The **Config.php** file is connecting to the database.

When the user is succesfully logged in the page is supposed to direct the user to the page called **login-hjem.php**. This file has the following php code in the start:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
```

The file called **session.php** looks like:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) {
header("Location: hjem.php");
}
?>
```

As said at the start, the file called **hjem.php* is the frontpage for not-logged-in users, and **dosnt'' have php session included. I don't need to protect password or encrypt them, because this is just a system for testing purpose. 
I hope you can help me out, what I have done wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do not call `session_destroy()`. it should be obvious that you're throwing away all session data when using this command...

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. That helps. Can I call the `session_destroy()` if I implement a logout button on the pages where users is logged in?

Comment: Yes @Elfernovich, `session_destroy()` should be called by a logout button ;)